# Unexpected behaviour of an igraph object with append function

Tags: r, list, igraph

I use `igraph` library in R to create graphs, then put them into a list. To this I am trying to `append` a new graph. Though the new element appends, it gets "unlisted".
Please advise how to prevent this behaviour. Expected is a list of graph objects.

```
library(igraph)

m1 <- matrix(c(1:3,2:4), ncol=2)
m2 <- matrix(c(1:4,2:5), ncol=2)

g1 <- graph.edgelist(m1)
g2 <- graph.edgelist(m2)

g_l <- list(g1)
(g_l <- append(g_l, g2))

> [[1]]
> IGRAPH eadfb20 D--- 4 3 -- 
> edges from eadfb20:
> [1] 1->2 2->3 3->4
> 
> [[2]]
> [1] 5
> 
> [[3]]
> [1] TRUE
> 
> [[4]]
> [1] 0 1 2 3
> 
> [[5]]
> [1] 1 2 3 4
> 
> [[6]]
> [1] 0 1 2 3
> 
> [[7]]
> [1] 0 1 2 3
> 
> [[8]]
> [1] 0 1 2 3 4 4
> 
> [[9]]
> [1] 0 0 1 2 3 4
> 
> [[10]]
> [[10]][[1]]
> [1] 1 0 1
> 
> [[10]][[2]]
> named list()
> 
> [[10]][[3]]
> list()
> 
> [[10]][[4]]
> list()
> 
> 
> [[11]]
> <environment: 0x000002d578c2eb70>
```

Here is an expected output:

```
> [[1]]
> IGRAPH eadfb20 D--- 4 3 -- 
> edges from eadfb20:
> [1] 1->2 2->3 3->4
> 
> [[2]]
> IGRAPH eadfe8b D--- 5 4 -- 
> edges from eadfe8b:
> [1] 1->2 2->3 3->4 4->5
```

Comment: You should use `append(g_l, list(g2))` then you will get what you want.

Comment: If you would like a list of two lists, you won't append one to the other. You need to use `list`. `list(g1, g2)`

Comment: MrFlick thank you, your suggestion works. If you write it as an answer, I will accept.Kat, with your approach I cannot add new elements later.